# For a continuous function $f$ with $f (1) > 0$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in (1-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I think I may have a solution, but I'm not sure if the proof is sufficient. I started first by assuming the converse is true to prove the theorem by contradiction, that is assume $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with $f(1) > 0$. Then $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (1-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$. We define some $\delta = f(1)$. Then,
$$ f(1) - f(1-\epsilon) > \delta \quad \& f(1) - f(1+\epsilon) > \delta $$ for any $\epsilon$. Therefore, $f$ cannot be continuous, but this contradicts our assumption, thus our theorem must be true.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$ is not $f(x) <0$ for all $x \in (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$. It is $f(x) \geq 0$ for **some** $x \in (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$. So your argument fails.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be such that $|f(x)-f(1)| <f(1)$ for $|x-1| <\epsilon$. Then,
by reverse triangle inequality we get $f(x)\geq f(1)-|f(x)-f(1)| >f(1)-f(1)=0$ for $|x-1| <\epsilon$.

Comment: I understand that I negated the theorem incorrectly, but I don't quite understand your proof still. It seems you started by using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity to put some constraints on $\epsilon$, but I don't understand the jump to the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: $f(1)-f(x) \leq |f(x)-f(1)|$ since $y \leq |y|$ for any real number $y$. The inequality I used is just a re-wrting of $f(1)-f(x) \leq |f(x)-f(1)|$. @Important_man74